# Java Method Signatures and Interface

Tags: java, methods, interface

We know that method signatures include only method name and parameter lists but not method return types. So why am I getting compiler error for the following code since java does not differentiate between methods with same signature.

```
 public class InterfaceTest implements I2{

     public void hello(){  }

     public void world(){  }
}

interface I1{
    public int hello();
}

interface I2 extends I1{
  public void world();
}
```

Comment: Annotate `world()` Methods in class "InterfaceTest" with `@Override`. But it will still state that you have to override `int hellow()`

Answer (score 4):

You have not [`overloading`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) here, you are [`overriding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) and also [`hidding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) methods but not in a correct way.... there are 2 possibilities to solve your problem:

```
public class InterfaceTest implements I2{

    public void hello(int a){  }  // overloaded method

    @Override
    public int hello(){ return 1; }  // overriden method

    public void world(){  }   // this hides I1 method
}
```

Point is if you try this in a single class:

```
public void hello() {}
public int hello() {return 1;}
```

You will get `Duplicate method hello() in type YourClass` error, because to [`overloading`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) a method you must change the `FormalParameterListopt` of the signature:

> If two methods of a class [...] have the **same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent**, then the method name is said to be **overloaded**.

## Last but not Least point:

*method signatures include only method name and parameter lists but not method return types*

According [JSL §8.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4), when you declare a method:

```
MethodDeclaration:
    MethodHeader MethodBody

MethodHeader:
     MethodModifiersopt TypeParametersopt Result MethodDeclarator Throwsopt

MethodDeclarator:
    Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt )
```

So when you do this:

```
  public int hellow(int number) throws Exception;
//|      |   |      |           └ throwing an exception (Throwsopt)
//|      |   |      └──────────── receiving one int argument (MethodDeclarator FormalParameterListopt )
//|      |   └─────────────────── name hellow (MethodDeclarator Identifier)
//|      └─────────────────────── returning an int (Result)
//└────────────────────────────── is a public method (MethodModifiersopt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referring method `overriding` here not `overloading`. The return type must be the same as, or a subtype, of the return type declared in the original overridden method in the superclass/interface.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) the return-type is part of the declaration. And the declaration has to be the same in the implementing class. Also an extending interface inherits all the methods from the parent-interface so your hellow-method must match the hellow-method from i1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly because java **cannot** differentiate between methods with same signature (but different return types).

Let's see what happens in your case (assuming it was possible),

You can do the following,

```
InterfaceTest obj = new InterfaceTest();
obj.hellow(); // The compiler knows it returns void here.
i1 obj1 = new InterfaceTest();
obj1.hellow(); // The compiler thinks it return an int, when it doesn't return anything.
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of a method is part of its signature, your compile error is because your return type doesn't match the one declared in your intereface.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing an interface in a class, which  have the same name of method as the interface "hello()", so there are two case

1) If you are implementing a interface you should write concrete implementation of its methods in this case

1. public int hello();
2. public void world();

but you provided implementation of only one method

- "public void world()"

  so it will ask you to implement the other method which which will become part of this class.

2)When you provide the concrete implementation of the  public void world() method it will collide with your method **public void hello()**, now as the overridden method become a member of your class and your method have same parameter list so it will fails the condition of the overloading.

so this will fail both the overriding and overloading functionality.